# Low loading into cache speed

Tags: caching, infinispan

I'm using Infinispan 6.0.0 in a 3-node setup (distributed caching with 2 replicas for each entry, no writes into persistent store) and I'm just reading the file line-by-line and storing that lines' contents into the cache. The speed seems a bit low to me (I can achieve more writes onto the SSD (persistent storage) than into RAM with Infinispan), but there  isn't any obvious bottleneck in the test code (I'm using buffered input streams, and their limits certainly aren't reached. As for now, I'm able to write 100K entries each ~45 seconds and that doesn't satisfy me. Assume simplified code snippet:

```
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    cache.put(s.substring(0,2), s.substring(2,5));
}
```

And `CacheManager` is created as follows:

```
return new DefaultCacheManager(               
  GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder()
    .transport().addProperty("configurationFile", "jgroups.xml").build(),
  new ConfigurationBuilder()                          
    .clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_ASYNC).hash().numOwners(2)
    .transaction().transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL).lockingMode(LockingMode.OPTIMISTIC)
    .build());
```

What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully aware of all the asynchronous mode specialities, but I'd afraid that something in the two-phase commit (Prepare and Commit) might force some blocking RPC => waiting for network latency => slow down.

Do you need transactional behaviour? If not, switch them off. If you really need it, you may disable just the autocommit feature and load the cluster via non-transactional operations. Or, you may try one phase commits.

Another option could be mass loading via putAll (with tens or hundreds of entries, depends on your entry size), but routing of this message is not really smart. In transactional mode it could behave a bit better, I guess.

The last option if you just want to load the cluster fast and then operate on it could be transferring the bulk data to each node without Infinispan (using your own JGroups channel, or just with sockets), and loading all nodes with the CACHE_MODE_LOCAL flag.

Answer (score 1):

By default Infinispan follows the `Map.put()` contract of returning the previous value, so even though you are using the `DIST_ASYNC` cache mode you're still implicitly performing a synchronous `cache.get()` for every put.

You can avoid this in two ways:

- `configurationBuilder.unsafe().unreliableReturnValues(true)` will suppress the remote lookup for all the operations on the cache.
- `cache.getAdvancedCache().withFlags(Flag.IGNORE_RETURN_VALUES).put(k, v)` will suppress the remote lookup for a single operation.